# SPFx: Error in REST API call spHttpClient.get()

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, sphttpclient

In my child component:

I tried to make a rest call from spfx web part to get people results, but it throws errors.

`this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(query)`;

Error: can't read property get of undefined

I believe it's something related to context of web part or padata protocol rules. But I passed down the context from parent component to child.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I created a helloword webpart and could pass the context to the react component like below:

[image]

[image]

Can you have a check if the passed context is correct, if it does not work, can you share your project?

BR